# Invalid argument in R when running rpois function

Tags: r

The code I am trying to run is for a basic total number of goals predictor for AFL. It uses the `rpois` function but after I calculate the variables to pass to the function I get an error.

> Error in rpois(10000, Weighted_Away_Goals) : invalid arguments

Any ideas how to fix this error?

```
    Poisson_AFL_Model <- function(Home_Team,Away_Team,Venue,total_goals)

  Home_Scored=HomeStats.Venue[HomeStats.Venue$Home == Home_Team & HomeStats.Venue$Venue == Venue, c('HG')] 
  Home_Conceded=HomeStats.Venue[HomeStats.Venue$Home == Home_Team & HomeStats.Venue$Venue == Venue,c('HGC')]
  Average_Home_Scored=MeansVenue[MeansVenue$Venue == Venue,c('HG')]
  Average_Home_Conceded=MeansVenue[MeansVenue$Venue == Venue,c('AG')]
  Away_Scored=AwayStats.Venue[AwayStats.Venue$Away == Away_Team & AwayStats.Venue$Venue == Venue, c('AG')]
  Away_Conceded=AwayStats.Venue[AwayStats.Venue$Away == Away_Team & AwayStats.Venue$Venue == Venue, c('AGC')]

  Average_Away_Conceded=MeansVenue[MeansVenue$Venue == Venue,c('HG')]
  Average_Away_Scored=MeansVenue[MeansVenue$Venue == Venue,c('AG')]

  Scaled_Home=Home_Scored/Average_Home_Scored
  Scaled_Away=Away_Scored/Average_Away_Scored
  Scaled_away_defence=Away_Conceded/Average_Away_Conceded
  Scaled_home_defence=Home_Conceded/Average_Home_Conceded
  Weighted_Home_Goals=Home_Scored*Scaled_away_defence
  Weighted_Away_Goals=Away_Scored*Scaled_home_defence

  xawayteam=rpois(10000,Weighted_Away_Goals)
  xhometeam=rpois(10000,Weighted_Home_Goals)


  Totalgoals=xhometeam+xawayteam
  MeanGoals=mean(Totalgoals)
  cat("\nHome Goals:", mean(xhometeam))
  cat("\nAway Goals:", mean(xawayteam))
  cat("\nMean Goals:", MeanGoals)
  cat("\nHome Wins from 10000:", sum(xhometeam>xawayteam))
  cat("\nAway Wins from 10000:", sum(xhometeam<xawayteam))
  cat("\nDraws from 10000:", sum(xhometeam==xawayteam))
  cat("\nTotal Goals:", total_goals)
  cat("\nMore than goals:", sum(Totalgoals>total_goals)/10000)
  cat("\nEqual to goals:", sum(Totalgoals=total_goals)/10000)
  cat("\nLess than goals:", sum(Totalgoals<total_goals)/10000)

}
```

Comment: There is a big difference between `"Weighted_Away_Goals"` and `Weighted_Away_Goals`

Comment: Ive tried both with and without "'s

Comment: What is the value of Weighted_Away_Goals before the call to rpois

Comment: Weighted_Home_Goals=14
 Weighted_Away_Goals=8.571429

Answer (score 0):

The rpois function is expecting a value. If you did
`xawayteam=rpois(10000,as.numeric(Weighted_Away_Goals))`
it would work.